# Weird Google Maps Glitch - IE7 - 8

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm currently coding a map using the google maps API... and it shows up weird in IE7-8 only.

[image]

For me, my code is pretty standard, to create a custom map.

```
function initialize(){
    var latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(45.484688,-72.960892);
    var settings={
        zoom:10,
        center:latlng,
        mapTypeControl:false,
        mapTypeControlOptions:{
            style:google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        navigationControl:false,
        navigationControlOptions:{
            style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"),settings);

    var contentString='<div id="content_map">'+'<h3>Title 1</h3>'+'</div>';
    var infowindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:contentString,maxWidth:200});
    var companyPos=new google.maps.LatLng(45.591459,-73.179245);
    var companyMarker=new google.maps.Marker({position:companyPos,map:map,title:"Groupe Québecon Montérégie"});
    //infowindow.open(map,companyMarker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(companyMarker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.close()
        infowindow.setContent(contentString)
        infowindow.open(map, companyMarker);
    }); 

    var contentString2='<div id="content_map">'+'<h3>Title 2</h3>'+'</div>';
    //var infowindow2=new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:contentString2,maxWidth:200});
    var companyPos2=new google.maps.LatLng(45.397004,-72.739792);
    var companyMarker2=new google.maps.Marker({position:companyPos2,map:map,title:"Groupe Québecon Estrie"});
    //infowindow.open(map,companyMarker2);
    google.maps.event.addListener(companyMarker2, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.close()
        infowindow.setContent(contentString2)
        infowindow.open(map, companyMarker2);
    }); 
}
window.onload=function(){initialize();}
```

So now, what is going on? I'm in the process to see if a CSS class could be interfering, but I still had no luck yet for finding the class/id of the marker.

Answer (score 0):

you can target your map pins for ie7-8 using conditional comments, i've used a similar technique with bing maps;

div#content_map{left:-10px;}

although i just noticed that the same id is being applied to each marker; id's are unique, so you're going to need to change one, which is the easiest way for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's promising... just got to find a css class or id to hook on. Which is a challenge by itself.

I tested it, and seems like I can change CSS of the google maps from my main CSS sheet.

Comment: aren't the two divs being constructed in the JavaScript the one we are talking about? If not, i'm really lost now, but you can use your browsers dev tools to inspect the element(s) and that should give you the css hook(s) you need. in my experience, i had to use a very lengthy declaration to override the proprietary maps' css.